# Copiando string armazenada em ponteiro

Tags: c, string, ponteiro

O que está errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str= "   teste";

    int j = 0;
    while(str[j] == ' ') j++;
    memcpy(str, &str[j], strlen(&str[j])+1);

    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Quando executo o codigo só obtenho como saída:

```
Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Enquanto que esperava que os espaços fossem removidos de `str`, algo proximo a função `trim()` do javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiser usar o `memcpy()` mesmo tem que copiar para outro lugar, não pode fazer em cima da mesma *string*:

```
char *str = "   teste";
int j = 0;
while (str[j] == ' ') j++;
int size = strlen(str) - j + 1;
char *result = malloc(size);
memcpy(result, str + j,  size);
printf("%s", result);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/k43urS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bwzszwod-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Copying.c).

Ou pode fazer *inline* de forma muito mais simples:

```
char *str = "   teste";
while (*str++ == ' ');
str--;
printf("%s", str);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/A3gNJW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/spsqyfvb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Copying2.c).